# Unicode classes in regex with Python2

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible?

This code works in **Python3**:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.split(r'\W+', 'Les Misérables')
Out[2]: ['Les', 'Misérables']
```

But it does not work in **Python2**:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.split(r'\W+', u'Les Misérables')
Out[2]: [u'Les', u'Mis', u'rables']
```

This does not work either (tested on Linux with `es_ES.UTF-8` locale):

```
In [1]: import locale

In [2]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.UTF-8')
Out[2]: 'es_ES.UTF-8'

In [3]: import re

In [4]: re.split(ur'\W+', u'Les Misérables', re.U|re.L)
Out[4]: [u'Les', u'Mis', u'rables']
```

Is there any way to get regex working with Unicode in **Python2**?

**Note:** The question is about getting Unicode-aware matches. I know I can rewrite the above regex to separate words using only ASCII classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is that you're adding flags on the wrong place (flags should be the 4th param).

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(?u)\W+', u'Les Misérables')
[u'Les', u'Mis\xe9rables']
>>> re.split(ur'\W+', u'Les Misérables', 0, re.U)
[u'Les', u'Mis\xe9rables']
```

To avoid these issues I'd recommend using inline flags (like `(?u)` above).

Comment: Right, I was mispositioning the Unicode flag. Didn't know the `(?u)` expression. Seems useful.

Comment: you could use `flags=re.U` keyword argument.